# Который, которое, которая, которые

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология

"В недавно открывшейся возле моего дома букинистической лавке я уже успел приобрести **книгу** с красивой **обложкой**, **которая** показалась мне интересной."

К какому из существительных в данном случае будет относиться местоимение которая?

В старославянском, например, у меня такой проблемы бы не возникло, так как местоимения я/она/та точно бы указывали на месторасположение существительного, к которому они относятся:

*книга*
В недавно открывшейся возле моего дома букинистической лавке я уже успел приобрести **книгу** с красивой **обложкой**, **она же** показалась мне интересной.

*обложка*
В недавно открывшейся возле моего дома букинистической лавке я уже успел приобрести **книгу** с красивой **обложицею**, **яже** показалась мне интересной.

Answer (score 5):

В современном языке структура такого предложения с двойным смыслом будет рассматриваться **как  стилистическая погрешность.**

Возможное редактирование:

В недавно открывшейся возле моего дома букинистической лавке я уже успел приобрести книгу с красивой обложкой, **показавшуюся мне интересной.**

Розенталь http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/68.htm

4. Неправильный порядок слов в сложном предложении с придаточным определительным порождает двузначность или искажает смысл высказывания. Например, в предложении «**Студенты проходили практику в одном из цехов завода, который недавно был реконструирован»** – союзное слово который может иметь **двоякую соотнесенность** (был реконструирован один из цехов или завод в целом?), хотя по правилу слова который, какой, чем **замещают ближайшее к ним существительное в форме того же рода и числа.**

   Правка в одних случаях достигается **заменой придаточного предложения причастным оборотом.** Ср.: 1) ...в одном из цехов завода, недавно реконструированном; 2) в одном из цехов завода, недавно реконструированного.